# convert from hastable result into a string using Java Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, vb.net, hashtable

I have a result of type of:

```
EMailLabel: "Mailing address"
LogLabel: "User login"
LoginButton: "Enter the program"
```

And in order to manipulate this result by splinting it into pairs, I need to convert it into string using the following:

```
 function parse(str, separator) {
       var parsed = {};
       var pairs = 
       str.toString().split(separator);
       for (var i = 0, len = pairs.length, keyVal; i < len; ++i) {
       keyVal = pairs[i].split("=");
       if (keyVal[0]) {
       parsed[keyVal[0]] = keyVal[1];
    }
}
return parsed;
```

}
But in the instruction:

```
str.toString().split(separator);
```

returns me the value of:

```
{[object Object]: undefined}
```

And of nothing is turned into string.
If I use the same instruction like that:

```
str.split(separator);
```

Threw me the error of:

```
Uncaught TypeError: str.split is not a function
```

And from what I've searched on the web I saw that I have to convert the `str` which is a `Hashtable` result into string.
I did that but unfortunately without any success
Is someone to help me on this issue?

Comment: Could you clarify your "input" data and what you expect to get as "output" because now your function `parse` expects a string as input and returns a hash table(map, object). But in the title, you say that you want to convert *from* a hash table into a string.

Comment: xxxmmm yes You are right. What I need is the opposite. is to send table and receive string. Any help about?

Comment: Could you show how should the string look

Comment: I have it in the top of my question, as a Hashtable result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need something like this:

```
function parse(map, separator) {
   return Object.keys(map).reduce((data, key) => {
     data.push(`${key}${separator} "${map[key]}"`);
     return data;
   }, []).join('\n');
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: With some additions it made it perfect. Now I can handle it very easy. Thanks ones more